# Android fragment getting hidden under the action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

Got a weird problem. Contents of the fragment getting hidden under the action bar. Its a pretty basic drawer layout and a fragment.

[image]

New to android and don't know if this is how it is.
**I used margin just to pull this down, as you can see below. But this doesn't sound correct to me... please throw some light where am I going wrong. Thanks in Advance.**

[image]

Comment: are you using the ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY flag?

Comment: oh my goodness... yes! android:windowActionBarOverlay set to true... Thank you very much. Please add this as answer I will accept. @blackbelt

Comment: @Mouli : I know its a long time since this post was updated. But i am having the same issue now. I have added android:windowActionBarOverlay to false in my styles.xml but still part of textview is hidden behind my action bar. Am i adding it in the right place or should i add this somewhere else. Please help

Comment: Is your content wrapped probably in scroll view that on start "scroll" down the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the normal and expected behaviour if you set `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` (`android:windowActionBarOverlay`) . [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) the documentation

Comment: I know its a long time since this post was updated. But i am having the same issue now. I have added android:windowActionBarOverlay to false in my styles.xml but still part of textview is hidden behind my action bar. Am i adding it in the right place or should i add this somewhere else. Please help

Comment: Are you using the CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Yes . CoordinatorLayout for the app bar. I am using the default "Navigation Drawer" activity by android for my project. When i add a fragment, part of the textview hides behind the action bar

Comment: You need a special attribute in your XML in this case. Look for it

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. but special attribute??

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162465/framelayout-shown-above-appbarlayout

Comment: Thanks much. I was able to fix it by adding "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
to your parent view of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for many who see this question is to change the parent layout of the toolbar to `LinearLayout` (likely with a vertical orientation), as this type of layout does not allow its children to overlap.

For example, this layout in `activity_main.xml` will result in the fragment being below the toolbar, rather than behind it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting top margin of the fragment's layout to height of AcionBar worked, at last!!

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Don't know if this is a better solution but for me this is the only working solution.